# SSL with Codeigniter htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl

OK so i'm having a bit of trouble with .htaccess.

I'm using Codeigniter and have just installed a SSL certificate. It's working great except I don't get the blue bar in Firefox, it says 'Your connection to this site is only partially encrypted'

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (signin)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(signin)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I only want to force SSL on some pages, to start with the signin page (mydomain.com/signin). It seems to remove the index.php/ in the URL fine and it does seem to be forcing the SSL for that page but there's no blue bar :(

I also changed my base_url to the following in the config file to allow http and https:

```
$config['base_url'] = $config['base_url'] = "http".((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "s" : "")."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Any help is most appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is caused by having elements in your page which are downloaded using HTTP instead of HTTPS.

You need to make sure that you either reference all the elements in the page with relative URLs or absolute URLs with the proper protocol (HTTPS instead of HTTP).

Comment: Yeah already checked that, everything on the page is https, even links to external files/scripts.

Comment: Are you sure there is no CSS file or something which references other files using absolute URLs? You can check with Firebug to see all the requests.

Comment: Yeah there was in the CSS but I have changed it and there's still no blue bar.

Comment: I used Firebug to check the requests under the Net tab, quite a few of my images and CSS files have a status of 301 (permanently moved). Could that be causing the issue?

Comment: I don't think the status response affects in any way as long as the connection is done via HTTPS. But you could make a test and remove the requests to those images and see what happens. There would be actually one note.. if the response status is 301, it means that the browser will try to download from the new location wherever that resource has moved to. So, you need to check if the new location is secured or not. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Ahhhhh yes it's working now! The issue was that I didn't add the assets folder (where all my images, CSS, js etc is stored). I just added it after signin and it's working perfect. Thankyou mazzucci!